# How to fix this issue?? AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.losses' has no attribute 'BinaryFocalCrossentropy'

Tags: python

````
```GETTING THIS ERROR
AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.losses' has no attribute 'BinaryFocalCrossentropy'
````

`AFTER COMPILING THIS CODE`

## Compile our model

METRICS = [
'accuracy',
tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')
]

adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryFocalCrossentropy(gamma=2.0, from_logits=True), metrics=METRICS, optimizer=adam)

Comment: Did you try to update the tensorflow package to the newest 2.10 version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.